# How to validate the values before saving a record through lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:inputField?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, spring18, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I'm using `lightning:recordEditForm` and `lightning:inputField` to update a record.
I need to validate the values before updation and I couldn't find any ways to get the values from `lightning:recordEditForm` or `lightning:inputField`.
How can I access the values from `lightning:recordEditForm` and `lightning:inputField`? Is it possible ?
If not why was it not allowed ?

Component:

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:attribute name="fieldList" type="String[]" default="['Name','Email','Birthdate','Languages__c','MobilePhone']"/>

    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact" onsubmit="{!c.submitData}">
        <lightning:messages />
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldList}" var="field">
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="inputs" fieldName="{!field}" />
        </aura:iteration>
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    submitData : function(component, event, helper) {
        var values = component.find('inputs');
        console.log('values',values);
        //Can't get the values.
    }
})
```

Comment: i am also stuck with same isue.. i have to validate a field based on value in another field. i do not want to go with validation rule and do this in component level itself. atleast required attribute should be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to bind the lighthning:inputField value to an Instance of an Object. Here is an Example code,

Parent Component:

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:attribute name="testContact" type="Contact" access="PUBLIC" default="{'sObjectType':'Contact'}"/>

    <div class="slds-box">
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEdit" objectApiName="Contact">
            <aura:iteration items="['LastName','Phone']" var="item">
                <c:inputFieldCmp aura:id="child" testContact="{!v.testContact}" fieldName="{!item}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </div> 

    <div  class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning:button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.recordSave}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Child Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="testContact" type="Contact"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldName" type="String"/>

    <lightning:inputField aura:id='inputField' fieldName="{!v.fieldName}" onchange="{!c.change}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Child Component Controller:

```
({
    change: function(cmp,event,helper){

        cmp.get('v.testContact')[cmp.get("v.fieldName")] =  event.getSource().get('v.value');

    }
})
```

Parent Component Controller:

```
({
    recordSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.testContact')));
    }
 })
```

On this Way you can simply bind the values to an Object Instance and Validate. Also you can make it possible with giving recordId attribute to the lighthing:recordEditForm by just make the record as that **testContact** attribute.

Comment: @am_Aravi " you can make it possible with giving recordId attribute to the lighthing:recordEditForm by just make the record as that testContact attribute."
can you explain how exactly? 
it works like the example you have shown, but i cant understand how to specify an id